# Disk error with luks/lvm

Tags: lvm, luks

My desktop PC no longer works. Now I want to use the data on my laptop. The disk is recognized by the laptop and can be decrypted, but the partition cannot be selected. It disappears from the file manager, leaving 2 partitions with around 700MB each.

The system was encrypted with LUKS and lvm during installation.

When I try to start the drive in the laptop, it says: "waiting for encrypted source device UUID = ...". Then he jumps into the shell. It roughly says: "busybox ... built-in-shell ... initframfs".

The output of `parted`:

```
mg@pc8:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] Passwort für mg: 
Modell: ATA TOSHIBA MK5061GS (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sda:  500GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: gpt
Disk-Flags: 

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   2330MB  1792MB  ext4
 3      2330MB  500GB   498GB


Modell: ASMT 2115 (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sdb:  256GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/4096B
Partitionstabelle: msdos
Disk-Flags: 

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe  Typ       Dateisystem  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB  primary   fat32        boot
 2      539MB   256GB   256GB  extended
 5      539MB   1305MB  767MB  logical   ext4
 6      1307MB  256GB   255GB  logical


Fehler: /dev/mapper/luks-039d7eaa-fc65-4262-8351-7a1e9bf633c6: unbekannte
Partitionstabelle
Modell: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)                                  
Festplatte  /dev/mapper/luks-039d7eaa-fc65-4262-8351-7a1e9bf633c6:  255GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/4096B
Partitionstabelle: unknown
Disk-Flags: 

Modell: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Festplatte  /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1:  2051MB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: loop
Disk-Flags: 

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem     Flags
 1      0,00B   2051MB  2051MB  linux-swap(v1)


Modell: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Festplatte  /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root:  496GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: loop
Disk-Flags: 

Nummer  Anfang  Ende   Größe  Dateisystem  Flags
 1      0,00B   496GB  496GB  ext4


Fehler: /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: unbekannte Partitionstabelle
Modell: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)                                  
Festplatte  /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt:  498GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: unknown
Disk-Flags:
```

And more information

```
mg@pc8:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                                           7:0    0  53,3M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/19457
loop1                                           7:1    0 349,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
loop2                                           7:2    0 118,2M  1 loop  /snap/core/15511
loop3                                           7:3    0  66,6M  1 loop  /snap/cups/980
loop4                                           7:4    0  91,7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop5                                           7:5    0 105,8M  1 loop  /snap/core/15925
loop6                                           7:6    0  66,6M  1 loop  /snap/cups/974
loop7                                           7:7    0  73,9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/864
loop8                                           7:8    0  73,9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/858
loop9                                           7:9    0  63,5M  1 loop  /snap/core20/2015
loop10                                          7:10   0 151,8M  1 loop  /snap/chromium/2614
loop12                                          7:12   0   9,6M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/235
loop13                                          7:13   0  63,4M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1974
loop14                                          7:14   0   9,6M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/229
loop15                                          7:15   0 349,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop16                                          7:16   0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop17                                          7:17   0 485,5M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop18                                          7:18   0  40,8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20092
loop19                                          7:19   0 485,5M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/126
loop20                                          7:20   0 151,8M  1 loop  /snap/chromium/2623
sda                                             8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0   1,7G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                                          8:3    0 463,6G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt                                253:0    0 463,6G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgxubuntu-root                          253:1    0 461,7G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgxubuntu-swap_1                        253:2    0   1,9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                                             8:16   0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                                          8:17   0   512M  0 part  /media/mg/BCD6-CA9E
├─sdb2                                          8:18   0     1K  0 part  
├─sdb5                                          8:21   0   731M  0 part  /media/mg/8c2c3833-b1cc-4c28-9f02-d0d649a8caa2
└─sdb6                                          8:22   0 237,3G  0 part  
  └─luks-039d7eaa-fc65-4262-8351-7a1e9bf633c6 253:3    0 237,2G  0 crypt 
sr0                                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
mg@pc8:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: UUID="IZf4uI-UcRE-jPtt-m93P-dXa4-mfPe-h93LoS" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1: UUID="45855fb3-7a8b-4f16-8aa8-156d3d7ca929" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root: UUID="dd9344cf-fc3d-4278-a5f1-6bbb018e0fbd" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: UUID="2B35-D824" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="2e987e37-544e-4ce0-b4e9-c87f521ee04e"
/dev/sda2: UUID="25eab6ea-3499-4f54-8378-30afa4b4e907" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7a2cab68-4dfc-4486-877c-1074e30fb658"
/dev/sda3: UUID="4b4a633c-74fd-41b6-912a-2efae7f9b4d2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="0fe760e3-8b6f-4939-b527-1081a7b02caf"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="8c2c3833-b1cc-4c28-9f02-d0d649a8caa2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8ad92106-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="BCD6-CA9E" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="8ad92106-01"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="039d7eaa-fc65-4262-8351-7a1e9bf633c6" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="8ad92106-06"
/dev/mapper/luks-039d7eaa-fc65-4262-8351-7a1e9bf633c6: UUID="3WhoLZ-22XV-PCiv-ZNB3-D5f1-105H-tddIz0" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

And more information

```
mg@pc8:~$ sudo pvs
  WARNING: VG name vgxubuntu is used by VGs A9iK2E-AbGe-lbMR-6Aod-Okml-1FYR-vBAjAy and 2PBMlD-34MD-84P0-UrJv-RKdw-9dG5-1JhLdO.
  Fix duplicate VG names with vgrename uuid, a device filter, or system IDs.
  PV                                                    VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree 
  /dev/mapper/luks-039d7eaa-fc65-4262-8351-7a1e9bf633c6 vgxubuntu lvm2 a--  <237,24g 32,00m
  /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt                                vgxubuntu lvm2 a--   463,57g     0 
mg@pc8:~$ sudo vgs
  WARNING: VG name vgxubuntu is used by VGs A9iK2E-AbGe-lbMR-6Aod-Okml-1FYR-vBAjAy and 2PBMlD-34MD-84P0-UrJv-RKdw-9dG5-1JhLdO.
  Fix duplicate VG names with vgrename uuid, a device filter, or system IDs.
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree 
  vgxubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n- <237,24g 32,00m
  vgxubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n-  463,57g     0 
mg@pc8:~$ sudo lvs
  WARNING: VG name vgxubuntu is used by VGs A9iK2E-AbGe-lbMR-6Aod-Okml-1FYR-vBAjAy and 2PBMlD-34MD-84P0-UrJv-RKdw-9dG5-1JhLdO.
  Fix duplicate VG names with vgrename uuid, a device filter, or system IDs.
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   vgxubuntu -wi------- 236,25g                                                    
  root   vgxubuntu -wi-ao---- 461,66g                                                    
  swap_1 vgxubuntu -wi------- 976,00m                                                    
  swap_1 vgxubuntu -wi-ao----   1,91g
```

And more information

It would be very good if the renaming meant that the disk could be booted in another PC.

Do I understand correctly that this command does this?

```
vgrename 3WhoLZ-22XV-PCiv-ZNB3-D5f1-105H-tddIz0 newId-123
```

More information

The problem has changed. I now want to boot the hard drive normally from another PC. Then the same message appears as described at the beginning.

"waiting for encrypted source device UUID = ...". Then he jumps into the shell.

I think the problem has nothing to do with duplicate names. Where is the problem? What would you try?

Comment: can you show `lsblk` and `blkid` also (with unlocked drive)?

Comment: `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`?

Comment: LVM doesn't like duplicate VG names, it's a common issue you should find various answers for, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495675/30851